# Tableau of Numbers in a Snake-like Pattern

Tags: matrices

I have matrix $99$ by $99$, this matrix looks like this:

We start with the left side $( 1 )$ and go to the right to $99$. Next we go one down $100$ and we go from right to left $101, 102, 102.. 198.$ Next we go down to $199$ and reply to right.

How can I designate coordinates from this?

For example I have this number:

$3$ - coordinates is $(2,0)$

$199$ - coordinates is $(0,2)$

$202$ - coordinates is $(3,2)$

The matrix in question:

1   2   3   4   5   6   ... 99

198 197 196 195 194 193 ... 100

199 200 201 202 203 204 ... 297

Comment: it does not matter one or zero

Comment: Yes, it *does* matter. I assumed 0 in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number $m = 100k + j$, where $j\in\{0,\ldots,99\}$ then you find it at position $(j,k)$ if $k$ is even and  $(99-j,k)$ if $k$ is odd. You have $j = m\mod 100$ and $k = m\operatorname{div}\,100$. If you want a closed form, here is one: $m = 100k + j$ is at position
$$
\left(\frac{99}2 + (-1)^k\left(j-\frac{99}2\right),k\right).
$$

Comment: i make mistake, I have matrix 99x99. the formation of the matrix is the same , left to right

Comment: Your new pattern does not really make sense. In the first row we have 99 numbers, while in all others, we have 100 numbers. Is that intended?

Comment: 1   2   3   4   5   6   ... 99
198 197 196 195 194 193 ... 100
199 200 201 202 203 204 ... 297     something like this

Comment: @JWa If you made a mistake in your question you have to edit your question and not write contradicting additions in comments.